# html hyperlink not working on chrome

Tags: html

Edit: I have corrected my code below just for beginners like myself. The hyperlink is working now

I am new to HTML and I am trying to learn how to create hyperlinks using HTML.
No matter what I do I can't get that hyperlink working.

My complete code. Just in case there is error in some other parts.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<h3>heading one</h3>
<h2>heading two</h2>
<title>html start</title>
<body>
<p>body starts here</p>
<p><strong>Hello world first paragraph</strong></p>
<p>this is the second paragraph<br>and this is a part of the second paragraph</p>
<p>body ends here</p>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a> try this

Comment: if you are weak in HTML, learn from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

Comment: Usually "did you try Google" is not an appropriate comment here, but in this case it is, had you typed `a herf` in Google, Google would have corrected it to `a href`, at least so for me...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I did try google. Sometimes you miss very simple stuff. Just let it slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`herf` is incorrect. Change it to `href`:

`<a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>`

[Some info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) here

Answer (score 0):

just change `<a herf="http://www.google.com/">link</a>` to `<a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>`